# Retrieving an audio file from a mysql Database, using Java

Tags: java, database, audio

Firstly I realise that this is a familiar question, it seems to pop up here all the time. Secondly, I am NOT storing the audio as a BLOB, I am storing the path to it!

Basically, I know I need to manipulate the result set but what I cant seem to get my head around is how to get the audio from the result set. I have done this with images, but not yet with audio. Any help would be much appreciated. Below is the code I used to get my image from the DB.

```
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);        

String images = "";         

while (rs.next()) {
images = rs.getString("path");
System.out.println(images + "\n");
System.out.println("TESTING - READING IMAGE");
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File(images));
System.out.println("img = " + images);
imagelabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(img));
imagelabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 200));
imageframe = new JFrame();
imageframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
imageframe.setSize(200,200);
imageframe.add(imagelabel);
imageframe.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);  
    System.out.println("DATA"+rs);
   
    musicfile = ""; 

    while (rs.next()) {
     musicfile = rs.getString("soundpath");
System.out.println("musicfile is:" +musicfile); InputStream in = new FileInputStream(musicfile);
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);   AudioPlayer.player.start(as);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You basically use the [Java Sound Api](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/). Read [Accessing Audio System Resources](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/chapter3.html) to read the audio file and read [Playing Back Audio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/sound/programmer_guide/chapter4.html) to play it.

NOTE: Didn't test this but since no one has answered yet, I wanted to show you where to look for.

Comment: {ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);  
System.out.println("DATA"+rs);
   
String musicfile = ""; 

while (rs.next()) {
musicfile = rs.getString("soundpath");   System.out.println("musicfile is:" +musicfile);
InputStream in = new FileInputStream(musicfile);
AudioStream as = new AudioStream(in);
AudioPlayer.player.start(as);}


I went back through my code myself there and this worked for me, I can play.wav files this way, thanks again for the help.